# Multiple argument in python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I want my script to take multiple argument with same name.

```
python3 script.py --test test1 --test test2 --test test3 --config config_path
```

How can I achieve this. I have tried `nargs` from argparse till now.

```
# My Solution
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Arg Parser',
            formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
            allow_abbrev=False)

parser.add_argument('--test', nargs='+', required=True, \
                help='Modules name for sanity check', choices=['test1 ', 'test2 ', 'test3 '])

parser.add_argument('--config')

arg = parser.parse_args()
```

But it's behavior is little different it takes it in the form

```
python3 script.py --test test1 test2 --config config_path
```

Any suggestion on how to get desired behavior

Comment: There's a 'append' `action value.  Check the docs.

Comment: Thanks  @hpaulj `append` works but I am seeing it like `test=[['train1'], ['train2']])` is this expected behavior.

Comment: What's your `nargs`? 'append' makes a list, nargs can add another layer.

Comment: I see ya, I was using `nargs='+'` which was causing this behavior. Removing this helped me solve the issue. This was great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be straight forward from @hpaulj comments adding code just in case

```
parser.add_argument('--test', action='append', required=True, \
                choices=['test1 ', 'test2 ', 'test3 '])
```