# Using Multiple Identical Arguments with Argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am using the **argparse** library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to parse arguments for a Python3 script. I would like to be able to specify a particular argument multiple times. For example:

`$ myscript -i host1 -i host2`

Using **parser.add_argument('-i', nargs='*')** allows multiple argument with **-i**. For example:

`$ myscript -i host1 host2`

However, I want multiple occurrences of **-i**. Is this possible? Right now a second use of the argument overwrites the first (in my initial example only 'host2' would be passed)

Comment: Just yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70165231/multiple-argument-in-python-argparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, if you use `action="append"`, it seems to do what you want.

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='append')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo 1 --foo 2'.split())
Namespace(foo=['1', '2'])
```

Comment: Yes! I overlooked the 'action' keyword argument. So the solution for me is `parser.add_argument('-i', action='append')`. Thank you!